# getting value from an option after condition jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have a select option where i need to choose a product and then a type of product.
After this both selection i need to select the category for it.
If i select a certain product and type it will automatically select a category for it and it will block the category option.

For that i made this condition:

```
 $( ".target" ).change(function() {
   var type  = $('.target[data-prod=type]').val();
   var product = $('.target[data-prod=product]').val();

     if (type == '1'  && product =='pillow') {
       $('#unhide').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.category').prop('disabled', true);

       $('div.cte select').val('color');   //this is wrong? not getting value of it after submit
     }else{
       $('#unhide').addClass('hidden');
       }

 });
```

BTW my category select option is dynamic:

```
<div class="form-group cte">
<label>Categoria</label>
 <select  name="categoria" class="form-control  category">


 <?php  
   $sel_cat = "SELECT category_name FROM gallery_category ORDER BY category_name ASC";    
   $run_cat = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_cat);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_cat)){
    echo ' <option value="'.$rows['category_name'].'">'.ucfirst($rows['category_name']).'</option>';  
   }
 ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

I want to get this option selected :

```
<option value="color'">Colors</option>
```

so i can get it value after submission.
i am geting my category value empty when i submit, what shall  i do?

obs:
(i'm not very good at jquery)

i know this php query is vulnerable, just made this way to make easy here.

Comment: Use `.val()` to get selected value, as of now you setting it

Comment: like this .val('value="color" ');   ?

Comment: `$('div.cte select').val();`

Comment: You are disabling your category select with `$('.category').prop('disabled', true);` which makes it's value empty on form submission. Check if you get the value without adding disabled property on select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding disabled property to form inputs makes them not available in submitted data. You are disabling your select in this line:

```
$('.category').prop('disabled', true);
```

That's why you are getting empty value. Try enabling it on form submission to allow data access, like this:

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function() {
  $('.category').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoded you could select it like this:

```
$('[name=categoria]').val( 3 ); // select with index :3
```

This wont work for you as you mentioned your options are dynamic so we need to select it from text:

```
$('[name=categoria] option').filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).text() == 'Colors'); //To select on the string Colors
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Or dynamically using the value:

```
$('[name=categoria] option').filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).val() == 'color'); //To select on the value color
}).prop('selected', true);
```